# How to calculate .MP3 file BPM(Beat per minute) in android

Tags: android

I am working an android application.How to calculate .MP3 file BPM(Beat Per Minute).Please

help me......................

Comment: what exactly is your question? You want to know how to code this? Or are you having problems with code you already wrote?